# Draw a regular graph on 8 vertices such that it does not have a K3 , and has no independent set of cardinality 4.

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Draw a regular graph(one which has all vertices of equal degree) on 8 vertices such that it does not have a triangle and has no independent set of cardinality 4.

I'm wondering if this is even possible? I've tried various graphs but this seems impossible. But how do I constructively prove this that it cannot be done?

Comment: It is a good practice to use the body of the Question to state the problem fully, the setup and the goal.  Then add context, such as what you tried or why the problem interests you.   Shortening the problem statement to fit into the title alone may introduce ambiguity, or at the least draw Readers' suspicions this might be so.

Comment: The question you have stated is uninteresting and trivial. A much more interesting question would be to draw a regular graph on $8$ vertices such that it does not have a $K_3$ and has **no** independent set of cardinality $4$. This example is related to the Ramsey number $R(3,4)=9$. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following graph has neither $K_3$ nor an independent set of size 4:

[image]

We take an 8-cycle, in which the biggest independent set has size at most 4, and make two vertices of each maximal independent set adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a $d$-regular graph on $8$ vertices that is triangle-free and has an independent set of size $4$.

1. For $d=0$ the edgeless graph on $8$ vertices is the only example.
2. For $d=1$ there is clearly also just one example.
3. For $d=2$ the $8$-cycle is an example, as is the union of two $4$-cycles.
4. For $d=3$ the cube graph is an example.
5. For $d=4$ the bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$ is an example.

For $d\geq5$ clearly $G$
cannot contain an independent set of cardinality $4$.